# How do I prevent my umap from being modified at every save?

Tags: unreal-4, git

I'm using UnrealEngine 4. Every time I save my files, my `.umap` file seems to be modified. I can basically generate an infinite stream of commits by just clicking `Save Current`, then committing changes, and clicking `Save Current` again, without making any actual changes.

To not create any unnecessary merge conflicts in `git` I would like the file to change only if something actually changed. How do I do this?